# Unreadable pagination

Tags: php, posts, wp-admin, pagination

I act according to the [Output of posts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIDId7lej80&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=5&t=912s)

There is a file blog.php

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Myblogpage
*/
?>

<?php get_header('third'); ?>


   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row">

         <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

            <?php /*if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); */ $query = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'post']);
            /*print_r($query);*/
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                ?>
            
            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <?php the_category($separator=' / ', '') ?>
                     <!--
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     -->
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb') ?><!--<img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-01.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image">--></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->
            
            <?php } 
            
            the_posts_pagination();
            
            ?>
            
            <!--<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>-->

            <!-- Pagination -->
            <!--
            <nav class="col full pagination">
                  <ul>
                  <li><span class="page-numbers prev inactive">Prev</span></li>
                      <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">6</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">7</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">8</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">9</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers next">Next</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
            -->
         </div> <!-- Primary End-->

         <div id="secondary" class="four columns end">

            <!--
            <aside id="sidebar">

               <div class="widget widget_search">
                  <h5>Search</h5>
                  <form action="#">

                     <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search here...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search here...'; }" value="Search here...">
                     <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">

                  </form>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_text">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Text Widget</h5>
                  <div class="textwidget">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                  Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                  nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus
                  a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. </div>
                 </div>

               <div class="widget widget_categories">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5>
                  <ul class="link-list cf">
                     <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_tag_cloud">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Tags</h5>
                  <div class="tagcloud cf">
                     <a href="#">drupal</a>
                     <a href="#">joomla</a>
                     <a href="#">ghost</a>
                     <a href="#">wordpress</a>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_photostream">
                  <h5>Photostream</h5>
                  <ul class="photostream cf">
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

            </aside>
            -->
            
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

         </div> <!-- Secondary End-->

      </div>

   </div> <!-- Content End-->

   <!-- Tweets Section
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="tweets">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="tweeter-icon align-center">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
         </div>

         <ul id="twitter" class="align-center">
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">2 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            <!--
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">3 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            -->
         </ul>

         <p class="align-center"><a href="#" class="button">Follow us</a></p>

      </div>

   </section> <!-- Tweets Section End-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

file functions.php

```
    <?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_theme');
add_action('wp_footer', 'scripts_theme');
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_register_nav_menu');
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets' );

function register_my_widgets(){

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Right Sidebar',
        'id'            => "right_sidebar",
        'description'   => 'Описание нашего сайдбара',
        'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => "</li>\n",
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => "</h2>\n",
        'before_sidebar' => '', // WP 5.6
        'after_sidebar'  => '', // WP 5.6
    ) );
}

function theme_register_nav_menu()
{
    register_nav_menu('top', 'Меню в шапке');
    register_nav_menu('bottom', 'Меню в подвале');
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post'));
    add_image_size('post_thumb', 1300, 500, true);

    // удаляет H2 из шаблона пагинации
    
    add_filter('navigation_markup_template', 'my_navigation_template', 2, 1 );
    function my_navigation_template( $template, $class ){*/
        /*
        Вид базового шаблона:
        <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
            <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
        </nav>
        */
        
    
        return '
        <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
        </nav>
        ';
        
    }

    // выводим пагинацию
    
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'end_size' => 1,
    ) );
        
}

function style_theme()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('default', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/default.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('layout', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/layout.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('media-queries', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/media-queries.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/modernizr.js');
}

function scripts_theme()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('localjquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.min.js');
    /*echo "<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>')</script>";*/
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerymigrate121', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('doubletaptogo', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/doubletaptogo.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('init', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/init.js');
}


?>
```

pagination settings

[image: pagination settings]

But as a result I get a page without pagination

[image: Mypage]

How to achieve pagination display?

Comment: Why are you using `$query = new WP_Query`? You’ve commented out the correct code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I use `$query=new WP_Query(['post_type'=>'post'])` instead `have_posts` because the option with `have_posts` doesn't work (doesn't display posts).

Comment: Have you referred to the template hierarchy? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview There’s no such thing as blog.php. You should use home.php or index.php with `have_posts()` to display a list of posts.

Comment: the new loop inside the main loop is extremely weird, also the youtube video you linked to is very long and in a foreign language with cyrillic text, it's unintelligible to those who don't speak that language (I'm assuming russian?). What are you trying to do? Is this meant to be a template for a blog? A category archive? This code is very weird. Pagination functions in WordPress always refer to the main query, not your new custom queries. If your main query returns no posts, then there are no pages to paginate because there are no posts. Your `new WP_Query` is an independent separate query